# Creating a Tester class won't compile

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a problem with my code, whenever I try to make a Tester Class, the code won't compile( my guess is that they are not linking with each other). However when they are not in tester form, they work perfectly.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class DistToline {
    public static double A;
    public static double B;
    public static double C;
    public static double distance;

    public static double
    getDist(double a, double b){
        distance= Math.abs(((A*a)+(B*b)+(C))/(Math.pow(A, 2))+(Math.pow(B, 2)));
        return distance;
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner f= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the A value for the line:");
        A = f.nextDouble();

        Scanner g= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the B value for the line:");
        B = g.nextDouble();

        Scanner h= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the C value for the line:");
        C = h.nextDouble();

        Scanner i= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the x coordinate of the point:");
        Double X = i.nextDouble();

        Scanner j= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the y coordinate of the point:");
        Double Y = j.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Distance from the point to the line is: ");
        System.out.println(getDist(2.17, -4));

    }
}
```

That is my full code, however when I make a Tester class, the codes are not linking with each other. I think this is because I haven't declared yet.

Here is my attempt on creating a Tester Class-

Tester:

```
class Tester{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner f= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the A value for the line:");
        A = f.nextDouble();

        Scanner g= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the B value for the line:");
        B = g.nextDouble();

        Scanner h= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the C value for the line:");
        C = h.nextDouble();

        Scanner i= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the x coordinate of the point:");
        Double X = i.nextDouble();

        Scanner j= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the y coordinate of the point:");
        Double Y = j.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Distance from the point to the line is: ");
        System.out.println(getDist(2.17, -4));

    }
}
```

Class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class DistToline {
    public static double A;
    public static double B;
    public static double C;
    public static double distance;

    public static double
    getDist(double a, double b){
        distance= Math.abs(((A*a)+(B*b)+(C))/(Math.pow(A, 2))+(Math.pow(B, 2)));
        return distance;
    }
```

The code is not stating any variables and they aren't even linking with each other. Is this because they are not declared? If so how would I fix it so that they are linking with each other?

Comment: Read your error messages?

Comment: cannot find symbol - method getDist(double,int)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the fact that your `getDist()` function is inside the `DistToline` class, but your mainline (`void main()`) is in the `Tester` class. You need to invoke the `getDist()` function by explicitly specifying the class it's in, as follows:

```
System.out.println(DistToline.getDist(2.17, -4));
```

Note this works because `getDist()` is declared as `static`. If `getDist()` were non-static, you would have to instantiate the `DistToline` class and call the function from the instance.

In your mainline you will also need to reference the variables `A`, `B`, and `C` the same way:

```
DistToline.A = f.NextDouble();
```

This is because they are static members of the `DistToline` class.

One more thing, although this won't affect the result: your `public static distance` variable can and should be moved into the `getDist()` function, as it doesn't need to be a static. Although you can just eliminate it altogether, and return the result of `Math.abs` directly:

```
public static double
getDist(double a, double b){
    return Math.abs(((A*a)+(B*b)+(C))/(Math.pow(A, 2))+(Math.pow(B, 2)));
}
```